Python wrapper for pool multiprocessing | AssertionError: data can be loaded only once
I am trying to train quite a few models from scikit on a bigger dataset (25k-250k rows with ~100columns)
The code looks something like this
def workers(params)
 X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test, classifier, ... = params
 training...
 assessing...
 return assessment, trainedmodel

def wrapper (X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test, classifier...)
 params = (X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test, classifier...)
 with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=workercount) as pool:
        results = pool.map(workers, params)
 pool.close()
 assessments, trainedmodels = zip(*results)
 return df, models

def anotherwrapper(X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test, classifier...)
 other code...
results2, models2 = differentwrapper(X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test, classifier...)
 ...other code...
 return ... resultscombined, models2...

def main()
 dataprep....
 resultscombined, ... models2, ... = anotherwrapper(X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test, classifier...)

and yields me
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
Traceback (most recent call last): 
pool.py line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
pool.py line 48, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
[[[mycode]]] line 336, in workers
    trainedmodel_post = thismitigator.fit(X_train_copy, Y_train_copy, sensitive_features=X_train[acolumn])
exponentiated_gradient [[[fairlearn]]] line 140, in fit
    lagrangian = _Lagrangian(
lagrangian [[[fairlearn]]] line 78, in __init__
    self.constraints.load_data(X, y, **kwargs)
[[[mycode]]] line 457, in trainandtestmitigatingmodel
    results = pool.map(workers, params)
pool.py line 367, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
pool.py line 774, in get
    raise self._value
AssertionError: data can be loaded only once


The problem only appears if I train a lot of models.
With just a few it does work just fine.
How can I have them each create their own copy of the data before use?
I've tried to change the workers to use
def workers(params):
    X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, classifier, parameters, sensitive_feature, mitigator, constraint, sensitive_feature_array = params
    X_train_copy = X_train.copy()
    X_test_copy = X_test.copy()
    Y_train_copy = Y_train.copy()
    Y_test_copy = Y_test.copy()

instead but to no avail.
